# Changing Reference List for author year/biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I am using author year together with biblatex. Q: How can I change the reference list: Instead of

> Name,S. (1930) Titel etc.
>   Name2, S2 (year) ....

I would like to have

> Name, S.
>     (1930)  Titel etc.
>
> Name2, S.
>     (year) , ....

If I have several items for the same author, then the reference list looks similar, but not for the first item.

Thanks ind advance (reference to the manual would be fine)

Here the code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}            
\usepackage[style=authoryear,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}            
\bibliography{mathematik_bibliothek}  
\begin{document}  
%%  
\nocite{achieser:1975,tao-compactness,tao:analysis1,tao:analysis2,schaefer:tvs}  
\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

There should be a break after Glasmann and the (1975) should be on the next line like in the case of Tao.
[image: Output of the code]

Comment: Can you please add two bib entrys you use to your question? And which bib style do you use? Other relevant packages for your bibliography?  That's the reason we like to ask for a MWE (minimal working example), a compilable code, we can copy to our computer and play with it to help you ...  BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: http://golatex.de/viewtopic,p,54294.html#54294

Comment: I have done this and I hope it is ok. I have to learn how to add code. Sorry.

Comment: [How do I mark code blocks?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) and [How do I mark inline code?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863)

Comment: The Tao entries can't be right if you want the year to appear on a separate line.  The `----` line simply means that the author is the same as the entry above.  Don't you want `Author name <line break> (1975). <rest of entry>`?

Comment: That's what I am looking for: A line break after the Author name **even** if there is only one item like in the Achieser and Glasmann case. It should then looks like in the Tao-case,i.e.

'Achieser, N.
 - (1975) Theorie ...
 Schaefer, H.
 - (1971) ...'

Comment: Still learning how to enter code: It should looks like

"Achieser, N."
"- (1975) Theorie .."
Schaefer, H.
- (1971) Topological .."

Comment: Hope now it works: It should looks like

`Achieser, N.`
`--(1975) Theorie ...`
`Schafer, H.`
`-- (1971) Topological ..`

Comment: Sorry, still learning how to enter text in the right way.  Anyway: `Author name <line break> - (year) entry` is what I want.

Comment: You might like the `philosophy-modern` style of [`biblatex-philsophy`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-philosophy) then. The modifications to get this are quite involved, but this style has already done it for you.

Comment: Do you think your question could be a duplicate of [BibTeX style that groups by author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/961/35864) or [Biblatex: creating an author-date style in multiple lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269268/35864)? If you don't feel that your question is a duplicate an explanation of what exactly is different would be extremely helpful.