# Biblatex: creating an author-date style in multiple lines

Tags: biblatex, formatting

I'd like to create an author-date bibliography style for biblatex, in which the author's name features in a line by itself, followed by entries labeled by the year; for instance:

```
BAL, Mieke
2005     Narratology. Toronto: University of Toronto Press.
         Trans. Christine Van Boheemen.
2013     Thinking in film. London: Bloomsbury.
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Have a look at [`biblatex-philsophy`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-philosophy), specifically its `philosophy-modern` style.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe! The philosophy-modern style is exactly what I want.

Comment: See also [BibTeX style that groups by author](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/961/35864)

Answer (score 1):

As @moewe mantioned in his comment, the philosophy-modern style included in the biblatex-philosophy package is exactly what I want.