# Get the bibliography style of Kelley's book General topology using bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

I would like to get the `bibliography style` of the Kelley's book *General Topology*:
[image]
[image]

I've been reading the options that `LaTeX` has [here](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) and there is no one like Kelley's book apparently.

Is it possible to get what I want?

Thanks

PD: I haven't said it but it is supposed to use the standard `bibtex`, i.e. `data_base.bib` + `style_file.bst`, but I don't mind if I would need extra packages. @AlanMunn says with that option is difficult. Please fell free to give another solution. I'm focus on only in the style, not in the way.

**Addendum**.

Following @moewe's advice I'm going to highlight what is the main part I want to recreate. It is obviously the format

Author (in `sc`)
  Cite (indented and restarted with each new atuthor).

The format of the proper cite doesn't mind. For example, I would like

Title (Edition), Editorial, Country (Year). Notes

for books and maybe

Title, Journal, Volume (in `bf`) Pages (year) for journals,

but it doesn't matter at all.

What I would like to have a field *subtitle* to be able to write subtitles right, because sometimes they are written in *note* fields.

And finally, if I use `\cite{kuratowski:topologie2}`, I want to obtain Kuratowski [2] automatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, "the standard bibtex" with `\bibliography{bib_data_base}` is not `biblatex` with which you tagged your question and which you included in the title... If this is indeed a requirement, please retag and edit the title.

Comment: No, it has been a mistake, sorry. I have the `packages` isolated in another file, so when I've looked the main document I've only seen the `\bibliography{bib_data_base}` command. I'm going to delete that part. I mean the `bibtex`, i. e. `file.bib` + `file.bst`.

Comment: I meant you are not intending to use `biblatex` at all, as it seems. `\bibliography{bib_data_base}` would be appropriate for `bibtex` with `style.bst`. So I was not asking you to reformulate your question, but simply to substitute `biblatex` in your tags and in your title for `bibtex` so that people are not mislead by them.

Comment: Oh, you're completely right. I was thinking in `bibtex` all the time, I didn't realize I had written `biblatex`. My apologies. I'll change the tag inmediately.

Comment: Ok, I think now it shoul be correct.

Comment: Thanks. As a byproduct, the chance of you getting the attention of the right people, just increased.  :)

Comment: I wonder if I'm the only person here who used that book as a graduate text, before almost anyone else here was born.

Comment: @gusbrs: It seems no experte in `bibtex`likes my question... :(

Comment: @Dog_69, it is not a question of liking it. It looks hard. I don't know how I would do it with biblatex, which I know better, and which is much more flexible and customizable than standard bibtex. I wonder how hard that might be within bibtex. Second, you did not provide folks with a MWE, and thus did not show what you had attempted. This may be a deal breaker to many. I suggest you three (non excluding) possibilities. 1) provide a MWE, that would increase the chance of getting an answer and would also bump the question; (continues...)

Comment: (continued) 2) flexibilize the bibtex requirement, biblatex indeed has more potential for customization; 3) add a bounty to your question.

Comment: The reason it doesn't have a LaTeX equivalent might probably be because this is a terrible style.

Comment: @percusse: Really? I love it. It seems me very beautiful. Why do you hate it?

Comment: `biblatex-philosophy`'s `philosophy-modern` style looks very, very remotely like this (if you squint really hard and close one one completely). It's quite different, but it shows that something like this is not entirely impossible. The biggest problem with a style like this is that it is so very unusual. People know and can deal with author-year citations and they know numeric citation styles. They even know numeric citation styles that add the author. But the fact that the number resets for each author is definitely unusual at first.

Comment: It's subjective of course but few obvious ones are; can't handle same- or similar-named authors (load on the reader for no good reason), can't handle citing multiple authors and so on.

Comment: You may want to emphasise in your question what particularly it is about this style that you want to recreate. Writing a complete style is a huge ask, and such requests are not really suitable on this site. You may have a better chance of getting an answer if you focus on one particular abstract question. Note that the style is inconsistent when it comes to punctuation: Compare an contrast Kuratowski [1] and Landau [1].

Comment: I would be very surprised if you'll find anyone willing to do this for you using standard `.bst` methods. At best some of the `biblatex` folk might be willing to try a `biblatex` solution, but if that's not acceptable to you, then you should tell us, because the style has very little practical use other than recreating this particular text.

Comment: @AlanMunn: I accepts every possible answer that recreates the style. I don't mind if the solution uses `bibtex`, `biblatex`, an extra `package`...

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/961/bibtex-style-that-groups-by-author/5057 could help

Comment: @Dog_69 Ok, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @samcarter: Yes. In fact if I could change the format to get [1] instead of [2018] it would already be. Do you think I should modify my question or delete it and ask a new question to modify that? Thanks.

Comment: I think your question is as clear as it's going to get, and as @moewe already pointed out, this format is kind of like `philosophy-modern` which is the same as the style Sam linked to.  So I don't think there's much to be gained from adding that code here. The issue of sub-numbering the items per author is the main one, and anyone who's reading this by now understands that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I focused on the 'interesting' bit of the style: The author+number citation and rough bibliography layout. The remaining tweaks should be doable with a bit of research on this site.

If we base our style on `biblatex-philosophy`'s `philosophy-modern` we only need to make sure that citations are not 'author year', but 'author number' instead.

I can't think of a simple way to do that at the moment (feature request is out: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/718), so I came up with the following. We pretend that we use an alphabetic style that uses only the author names in its label. Normally `style=alphabetic` uses only bits of the author name and the year (e.g. SR98, Knu84). If a label is ambiguous, Biber calculates an `extraalpha` value (e.g. Knu86**a**, Knu86**b**). Since our labels are the names only, `extraalpha` would get us 'Nussbaum' (if there is no other work by 'Nussbaum') and 'Knutha', 'Knuthb'. That `extraalpha` is almost our number: If there is no `extraalpha` ('Nussbaum') we take 1, otherwise `extraalpha` is what we go with.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, backend=biber, labelalpha, giveninits, uniquename=init, mergedate=false, volnumformat=plain]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field{labelname}
  }
}

\renewbibmacro*{relateddate}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}
\renewbibmacro*{commarelateddate}{\usebibmacro{relateddate}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\renewbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \postsepyear{%
    \usebibmacro{extralabel}}}

\newbibmacro{extralabel}{%
  \iffieldundef{extraalpha}
    {\printtext[extraalpha]{1}}
    {\printfield{extraalpha}}}

\newbibmacro{cite:extralabel}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{extralabel}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:AY:noshorthand}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extralabel}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extralabel}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

`biblatex` 3.12  features a new `extraname` counter that we can use here instead of the hack with `extraalpha`. Simply replace `extraalpha` with `extraname` in the code above and drop `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate` and the `labelalpha` option.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern, backend=biber, giveninits, uniquename=init, mergedate=false, volnumformat=plain]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewbibmacro*{relateddate}{%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printtext[parens]{\printdate}}
\renewbibmacro*{commarelateddate}{\usebibmacro{relateddate}}

\renewbibmacro{date+extradate}{%
  \postsepyear{%
    \usebibmacro{extralabel}}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{extraname}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\newbibmacro{extralabel}{%
  \iffieldundef{extraname}
    {\printtext[extraname]{1}}
    {\printfield{extraname}}}

\newbibmacro{cite:extralabel}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{extralabel}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite:AY:noshorthand}{%
  \ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldundef{labelyear}}
       {\usebibmacro{cite:label}%
        \usebibmacro{cite:reinit}}
       {\iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
          {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extralabel}}
          {\printnames{labelname}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \usebibmacro{cite:extralabel}%
           \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}}
\makeatother

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{given-family}
\AtBeginBibliography{\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,worman,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Comment: Very clever! I hadn't thought about using the alpha style.

Comment: @AlanMunn It isn't ideal as the `alphabetic` style doesn't do name disambiguation as nicely as `authoryear`, but I couldn't think of a better way to get the numbers.

Comment: Why does it non work for me? :( . I have only replaced your bib file to my own file and cite other books.

Comment: @Dog_69 Did you manage to run the exact MWE from my answer without any modifications? Since the answer requires `biblatex`+Biber and you used to work with BibTeX, there may be things you need to modify in your workflow. Please have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864. I need to know what you tried, what exactly is not working, what warnings and errors you get.

Comment: I only change my` bib` file and the cited book. I'm using `TeXStudio` so I've follow the steps of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations but it doesn't work. An error messages appears:  Found biblatex control file version 3.4, expected version 3.3.
This means that your biber (2.7) and biblatex (3.10) versions are incompatible. So I don't get the bibliography list and all references appear in bold (as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number says).

Comment: I have tried to update `biber` with the `MikTeX` update but an error always happens, initexmf semms to fail. Something laike error 1 also ais shown.

Comment: @Dog_69 Mhh, the `initexmf` error is a generic error message. We would need to know more to be able to help. What exactly did you try? Did you make sure no TeX-related processes are still running before you ran the MikTeX Update tool? Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/108447/35864

Comment: I tried to update `miktek` with the app. And I'm sure no `TeX`file was runs neither open. Here is the last messages from the `log file`: running 'initexmf --force --mklinks --verbose'  initexmf: warning: The link target "C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\miktex-pdfsig.exe" does not exist.  Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed.

Comment: What app? Did you follow the steps from my last link? I.e. did you open the Package Manager, synchronise the package database and made sure that all `miktex-...` packages are installed? Have a look at https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/8

Comment: Also note that the line about `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\miktex-pdfsig.exe"` is only a warning. Is there an error message somewhere? Does it mention a `.log` file. Can you run each of the Updaters twice and see what happens?

Comment: I have just done it. Now I have been able to update everything. I have also run my `tex` file and it works. The `bibliography` looks like the yours. Thanks for all your comments with these so-valuable links. `+\infty` for all your work.